# get value from TextInput and pass to grandparent and to the child react native

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm new to react-native my component structure goes like this

```
MainScreen > LoginScreen  > Form         > UserInput
                          > ButtonSubmit
```

each one is a component
This is the form component

```
 export default class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
     };
   }

render() {
 return (
  <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.container}>
    <UserInput
      source={usernameImg}
      placeholder="Username"
      autoCapitalize={'none'}
      returnKeyType={'done'}
      autoCorrect={false}
    />
    <UserInput
      source={passwordImg}
      placeholder="Password"
      returnKeyType={'done'}
      autoCapitalize={'none'}
      autoCorrect={false}
    />
     </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
 }
}
```

This is UserInput component im calling UserInput component twice in the form one to get username and one for the password

```
export default class UserInput extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
   this.state = {
     username: '',
     Password:'',
    };
   }
 render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.inputWrapper}>
    <Image source={this.props.source} style={styles.inlineImg} />
    <TextInput
      style={styles.input}
      placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
      secureTextEntry={this.props.secureTextEntry}
      autoCorrect={this.props.autoCorrect}
      autoCapitalize={this.props.autoCapitalize}
      returnKeyType={this.props.returnKeyType}
      placeholderTextColor="white"
      underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
      onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({ username})}
      value={this.state.username}
    />
    </View>
   );
  }
 }
```

This is the loginScreen component that I have

```
export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
    <Form />
    <ButtonSubmit  />
  );
 }
}
```

This is my MainScreen component and its the parent

```
  export default class Main extends Component {
  render() {
   return (
    <Router>
      <Scene key="root">
        <Scene key="loginScreen"
          component={LoginScreen}
            animation='fade'
          hideNavBar={true}
          initial={true}
        />
       </Scene>
      </Router>
     );
    }
  }
```

onclick the button from the ButtonSubmit I need get the value of the 2 fields from Form component and that is using its  child component Userinput component? what will the best solution i can use for this?

Answer (score 2):

Lets take the simple case of a parent component and one child component (lets say it is a n input field).

You have two options for handling the state:
(1) All state in the parent component. The parent component passes as a prop, to the child component, a callback. Once the input in the child component is changed, the callback is called. Since it is in the parent component, the parent component can update the state.
(2) Using redux store and accessing it from multiple components.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using redux which is a predictable state container for javascript app , In redux we can create global state for the app and create action to change the state , It might take a while to wrap your head around it but it is sure a huge bonus to know redux.

follow this link to get a start
https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react

Answer (score 0):

In React the child components cannot send back values to parent components unless explicitly allowed to do so. 
You can just pass down a callback to child component and handle the input.

OR

What you can do is you can use [redux-form](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/) if you are using redux for your state management.

Here is the example, passing down callback to the child

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      value: ''
    };
  }

  //...

  handleChangeValue = e => this.setState({value: e.target.value});

  //...

  render() {
    return (
      <Child
        value={this.state.value}
        onChangeValue={this.handleChangeValue}
      />
    );
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
  //...

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        type="text"
        value={this.props.value}
        onChange={this.props.onChangeValue}
      />
    );
  }
}
```