# How to pass a function to child component by attrs

Tags: react-native

I want to reach value of TextInput in child component from Parent.

[get value from TextInput and pass to grandparent and to the child react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49687199/get-value-from-textinput-and-pass-to-grandparent-and-to-the-child-react-native)

There is an example above. but I'm using template and TextInput is created in different way(at least for me, I'm very new in react native.) like below.
I tried like that but I couldn't fire the onChangeValue method.

```
-----Child--------

import { TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

import styled from 'styled-components';

const CustomInput = styled(TextInput).attrs(({onChangeValue, placeholder, type, theme }) => ({
  placeholderTextColor: theme.colors.transparentGrayx,
  selectionColor: theme.colors.defaultWhite,
  underlineColorAndroid: 'transparent',
  secureTextEntry: type === 'password',
  autoCapitalize: 'none',
  textContentType: type,
  autoCorrect: false,
  placeholder,
  onChangeValue: onChangeValue
}))`
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: CircularStd-Book;
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.defaultWhite};
`;



type InputProps = {
  placeholder: string,
  iconName: string,
  type: string,
  onChangeValue : function,
};

const Input = ({ value, placeholder, iconName, type, onChangeValue }: InputProps): Object => (
  <ContentContainer
    color={appStyles.colors.transparentGray}
  >
    <InputWrapper>
      <InputIcon
        iconName={iconName}
      />
      <CustomInput
        placeholder={placeholder}
        type={type}
        value = {value}
        onChangeValue = {onChangeValue}
      />
    </InputWrapper>
  </ContentContainer>
);

export default Input;


-----Child--------

---Parent--------------
.
.

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onChangeValue = this.onChangeValue.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      value: ''
    };
  }
.
.

  onChangeValue = e => {
    console.log("dfdf")
  }
.
.
  renderInput = (
    placeholder: string,
    iconName: string,
    type: string,
    style: Object,
    onChangeValue : function
  ): Object => (
    <Input
      placeholder={placeholder}
      iconName={iconName}
      style={style}
      type={type}
      onChangeValue={onChangeValue}
    />
  );

.
.
return (
      <Container>
        <Animated.View
          style={emailAnimationStyle}
        >
          {this.renderInput(
            'E-mail',
            'email-outline',
            'emailAddress',
            emailAnimationStyle,
            this.onChangeValue()
          )}
        </Animated.View>

      </Container>
    );
---Parent--------------
```

Could someone help me please.

Answer (score 0):

There was a sample code.
component:

```
const UserInput = ({onChangeText}) => (

  <View>
      <TextInput onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}></TextInput>
  </View>
)
```

and here is component usage:

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.onChangeText = this.onChangeText.bind(this)

  }

  onChangeText(text){
    console.log(text)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <UserInput onChangeText={this.onChangeText}>

      </UserInput>
    )
  }
}
```